# how to return two values based on one condition?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to ask my user to select his/her astrological sign and then I would display potential days/months he/she was born.

It gets especially complex for me as one astrological sign is usually in between two months. And each month belongs to two astrological signs.

I was thinking about creating an object but I'm really not sure if this is the way to go.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: There are javascript libraries out there for astrology, look up on your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 3):

You may simply have an object with sign name as a key and respective months as a value:

```js
const getMonthsBySign = signName => {
    const signs = {
        Aries: ['March', 'April'],
        Taurus: ['April', 'May'],
        Gemini: ['May', 'June'],
        Cancer: ['June', 'July'],
        Leo: ['July', 'August'],
        Virgo: ['August', 'September'],
        Libra: ['September', 'October'],
        Scorpius: ['October', 'November'],
        Archer: ['November', 'December'],
        Goat: ['December', 'January'],
        Waterbearer: ['January', 'February'],
        Fish: ['February', 'March']
    }
    return signs[signName]
}

console.log(getMonthsBySign('Gemini'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: This answer looks very simple and correct, it could even be improved a bit by adding the days. Aries: {'March': 21, 'April': 20}

Answer (score 0):

This seems like mostly an opinion-based question, so any sort of code would be appreciated, but as it stands, probably the most intuitive way to return more than one result is to return an array with the different values. For example, if you were to return 2 or more months, you could return `["January", "February"]`.

Any code for more context would be helpful though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking the time to help.
What Yevgen Gorbunkov posted really helped.
I've edited the code slightly as my input is a number and I'm using this input to output a pair of months.
Here is my small tweak:

```js
      const getMonthsBySign = signName => {
    const signs = {
        1: ['March', 'April'],
        2: ['April', 'May'],
        3: ['May', 'June'],
        4: ['June', 'July'],
        5: ['July', 'August'],
        6: ['August', 'September'],
        7: ['September', 'October'],
        8: ['October', 'November']
    }
    return signs[signName]
}

firstMonth = getMonthsBySign('1')[0];
secondMonth = getMonthsBySign('2')[1];

console.log(firstMonth);
console.log(secondMonth);
```